# ANT task - multiple files - loop through

Tags: ant, fileset, xmltask

I have quite complicated ant task to write. I had to make separate builds files and 1 left. 
There are 4 files:

```
 buildpackage.bat, buildpackage.xml, buildpackage.txt, structure.xml
```

buildpackage.bat is just an ant file that calls `buildpackage.xml "ant -f buildpackage.xml"`. That is fine.

buildpackage.txt is simple and has got comma-separated lines:

```
server1,client1
server2,client2
genericserver,client[x]
server[x],client[x]
```

There is always server name and client name:

- `Server name` can be letters only, numbers and letters but has variable length.
- `Client name` - letters only.

I need to split those files into 2 separate variables: `server.name` and `client.name`.

What I have done is:

```
<loadfile property="buildpackage" srcFile="buildpackage.txt"/>    
<for list="${buildpackage}" param="depl.det" delimiter="${line.separator}">
 <sequential>
  <echo>
   Input:   @{deploy.details}
  </echo>
 </sequential>
</for>
```

The results I get are:

```
[echo] Input:   server_01,Client_01
[echo] Input:   server_02,Client_02
[echo] Input:   server_03,Client_03
[echo] Input:   clientserver,client_04
```

I would like server_01 to be parameter1 and client_02 to be parameter2.

I will perform other tasks in a sequence. I will copy files from client[x] directory to server[x] (that is simple but how do I split that string into 2 separate variables?).

And now the very complicated task.

I also have structure.xml file. The structure is:

```
 <core>
   <clients>
     <client>
       <name>Client_01</name>
       <branding>brand_01</branding>
       <applications>
         <application>application_01</application>
       </applications>
       <solutions>
         <solution>solution01</solution>
       </solutions>
   </client>
   <client>
     <name>Client_07</name>
     <branding>brand_09</branding>
     <applications>
       <application>application_03</application>
     </applications>
     <solutions>
       <solution>solution01</solution>
       <solution>solution07</solution>
       <solution>solution08</solution>
     </solutions>
   </client>
  <clients>
 <core>
```

I have plenty of clients, applications, brandings, solutions. Each client can have only 1 application and 1 branding but multiple solutions.

Based on previous sequential task (get server and name) I have to loop through that xml file and get for each matching client (from previous task)

```
- branding
- application 
- solutions (multiple or one)
```

I can read XML using `<xmlproperty>` but I do not know how to do it sequentially (iterate) and get matching properties.

I know it is complicated. The summary is:

1. build script starts
2. build script extracts data from buildpackage.txt as client.name and server.name
3. build script gets `${client.name}` from step 2 as a parameter and loops through structure.xml. It finds matching branding/application/solutions and outputs it for each matching client.

Output:

```
server.name
client.name
branding.name
application name
solution [X]
solution [y]
```

Ant has to be processed for each server/client. I can do the rest of the build and compile if I have the properties. I can not touch structure.xml. I can do all I need/want to buildpackage.cml and buildpackge.txt. Buildpackage.txt could be replaced by .xml file or any file (for example .properties). It has to contain those 2 values server and client.

Thank you for your help.

## EDIT

Now i have a problem. 
If I put same application 2x into a buildfile it builds only first one.
Here is my `build.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="DoTheJob" basedir="." xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib" xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">
    <!-- Define classpath and default locations-->
    <property name="root.dir" location="../.."/>
    <property name="dest.dir" location="packages"/>
    <property name="ant.lib.dir" location="../lib"/>
    <property name="repository_url" value="http://repository-url"/> 
    <path id="project.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${ant.lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/IIT/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement location="../savedjar/compiled.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="svnant.path">
        <fileset dir="../lib/">
            <include name="svnant.jar"/>
            <include name="svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.path" /> 
    <tstamp>
        <format property="build_time" pattern="YYYY MMMM dd HH:mm:ss"/>
    </tstamp>   
    <!-- Change characters to lowercase -->
    <scriptdef language="javascript" name="lowercase">
        <attribute name="string" />
        <attribute name="to" />
        project.setProperty(attributes.get("to"),attributes.get("string").toLowerCase());
    </scriptdef>
    <!-- Import XMLTask for XML transformations-->
    <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" classpathref="project.classpath"/>
    <!-- Define buildfiles locations-->
    <property name="structure.file" location="../structure.xml"/>
    <property name="buildpackage.file" location="buildpackage.txt"/>
    <!-- load client/server file-->
    <property file="${buildpackage.file}"/>
    <!-- loop over all clients --> 
    <xmltask source="${structure.file}">
    <call path="//client">
        <param path="name/text()" name="client"/>
        <param path="branding/text()" name="branding"/>
        <param path="applications/application/text()" name="application"/>
            <actions>
                <!-- loop through all XML properties only when @{client} condition is matched --> 
                <ac:if>
                    <isset property="@{client}"/>
                    <then>
                        <echo>=====================================================</echo>
                        <echo>Building package for @{client} on ${@{client}}       </echo>
                        <echo>=====================================================</echo>
                        <!-- creating destination directories -->                           
                        <delete dir="${build.dir}/@{client}"/>
                        <mkdir dir="${dest.dir}/@{client}"/> 
                        <echo>=====================================================</echo>
                        <echo>Copy application files code/temaplates to destination</echo>
                        <echo>=====================================================</echo>                      
                        <!-- creating code build directory -->
                        <mkdir dir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/code"/> 
                        <!-- copy application code --> 
                        <echo>copy application code</echo>
                        <copy todir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/code/application/@{application}" overwrite="yes">
                            <fileset dir="${root.dir}/client-source/application/@{application}" includes="**/*.*"/>
                        </copy>
                        <!-- copy application templates --> 
                        <mkdir dir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/@{client}"/> 
                        <echo>copy application templates</echo>
                        <copy todir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/@{client}" overwrite="yes">
                            <fileset dir="${root.dir}/applications/apps/@{application}" includes="**/*.*"/>
                        </copy>
                        <echo>===================================================</echo>
                        <echo>copy Solutions files code/temaplates to destination</echo>
                        <echo>===================================================</echo>    
                        <!-- nested xmltask for loop over solutions -->
                        <xmltask source="${structure.file}">
                            <call path="/core/clients/client[name/text()='@{client}']/*/solution">
                                <param path="text()" name="solution"/>
                                    <actions>
                                        <!-- making sure that solution is lowercase -->
                                        <lowercase string="@{solution}" to="solution.lowercase" />
                                        <echo>copy solutions code</echo>
                                        <!-- copy solutions code -->
                                        <copy todir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/code/solutions/${solution.lowercase}" overwrite="yes">
                                            <fileset dir="${root.dir}/client-source/solutions/${solution.lowercase}" includes="**/*.*"/>
                                        </copy>
                                        <!-- copy solutions templates -->
                                        <echo>copy Solutions templates</echo>
                                        <copy todir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/@{client}" overwrite="yes">
                                            <fileset dir="${root.dir}/applications/solutions/${solution.lowercase}" includes="**/*.*"/>
                                        </copy>
                                    </actions>
                            </call>
                        </xmltask>
                        <echo>==============================================</echo>
                        <echo>copy Client files code/temaplates to destination</echo>
                        <echo>==============================================</echo> 
                        <!-- copy branding directory --> 
                        <copy todir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/@{client}" overwrite="yes">
                            <fileset dir="${root.dir}/applications/brandings/@{branding}" includes="**/*.*"/>
                        </copy>                         
                        <!-- copy client code --> 
                        <copy todir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/code/client/@{client}" overwrite="yes">
                            <fileset dir="${root.dir}/client-source/client/@{client}" includes="**/*.*"/>
                        </copy>                         
                        <!-- set templates directory --> 
                        <copy todir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/@{client}" overwrite="yes">
                            <fileset dir="${root.dir}/applications/clients/@{client}" includes="**/*.*"/>
                        </copy>         
                        <echo>==============================================</echo>
                        <echo>compiling code                                </echo>
                        <echo>==============================================</echo> 
                        <!-- making classes directory --> 
                        <mkdir dir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/classes"/>
                        <javac destdir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/classes" classpathref="project.classpath" debug="on" fork="true" includeantruntime="false" memoryinitialsize="256m" memorymaximumsize="1024m">
                            <src path="${dest.dir}/@{client}/code/"/>
                        </javac>
                        <echo>==============================================</echo>
                        <echo>creating Client.jar                           </echo>
                        <echo>==============================================</echo> 
                        <!-- jar classes directory --> 
                        <jar jarfile="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/Client.jar" basedir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/classes"/>
                        <!-- reaplce text in files --> 
                        <replaceregexp byline="true">
                            <regexp pattern="@ReleaseDate@"/>
                            <substitution expression="${build_time}"/>
                            <fileset dir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/@{client}/templates/">
                                <include name="*.htm"/>
                                <include name="*.html"/>            
                                <include name="*.ini"/>
                            </fileset>
                        </replaceregexp>
                        <!-- get svn info --> 
                        <svn username="********" password="************" javahl="false" svnkit="false">
                            <info target="${repository_url}" />
                        </svn>
                        <!-- creating Client.ini file --> 
                        <touch file="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/Client.ini"/>
                        <concat destfile="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/Client.ini" append="true">releaseDate=${build_time}${line.separator}</concat>
                        <concat destfile="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/Client.ini" append="true">svnrevision=${svn.info.lastRev}${line.separator}</concat>
                        <!-- ziping package --> 
                        <zip destfile="${dest.dir}/@{client}/@{client}.zip" basedir="${dest.dir}/@{client}/app/" />
                        <echo>==============================================</echo>
                        <echo>sending @{client}.zip to the server via scp      </echo>
                        <echo>==============================================</echo> 
                        <!-- scp file to remote server -->
                        <property name="scp_username" value="**********"/>
                        <property name="scp_password" value="**********"/>
                        <property name="scp_server" value="${@{client}}"/>
                        <property name="scp_remote_directory" value="*********"/>
                        <scp trust="true" verbose="true" localFile="${dest.dir}/@{client}/@{client}.zip" remoteTodir="${scp_username}:${scp_password}@${scp_server}:${scp_remote_directory}"/>  
                        <echo>${line.separator}${line.separator}${line.separator}</echo>
                    </then>
                </ac:if> 
            </actions>
        </call>
    </xmltask>
</project>
```

And if I try yo build `buildpackage.txt` file

```
client1=server1
client2=server1
client1=server2
```

I do get 
client1->server1, client2->server1 but ...... no client 1to server2

## EDIT2

All fixed.
The solution for scp task is:

```
       <!-- scp file to remote server -->
        <property name="scp_username" value="XXX"/>
        <property name="scp_password" value="YYY"/>
        <property name="scp_remote_directory" value="path"/>
        <for list="${@{client}}" delimiter="=" param = "val">
            <sequential>
            <property name="token" value="@"/>
            <scp trust="true" verbose="true" localFile="${dest.dir}/@{client}/@{client}.zip" remoteTodir="${scp_username}:${scp_password}${token}@@{val}:${scp_remote_directory}"/> 
        </sequential>
        </for>
```

All works.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any xmldriven build i recommend using the ant addon [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/), so something like :
(assuming that clientnames are similar in buildpackage.txt and structure.xml - your snippet has several names Client_01, client1 .. !?)

```
<project>
 <!-- Import XMLTask -->
 <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>

 <!-- make buildpackage.txt a valid propertyfile to get the job done
      f.e. server1,client1 will get client1=server1 etc. ..
      to make server easily accessible within xml loop
 -->
 <replaceregexp
   file="buildpackage.txt"
   match="(.+),(.+)"
   replace="\2=\1"
   byline="true" />

 <!-- now load that file -->
 <property file="buildpackage.txt"/>

 <!-- loop over all clients --> 
 <xmltask source="structure.xml">
  <call path="//client">
   <param path="name/text()" name="client"/>
   <param path="branding/text()" name="branding"/>
   <param path="applications/application/text()" name="application"/>

   <!-- inside action adress params with @{..} syntax ! -->
   <actions>
    <!-- the copy (or whatever) action
         here demonstrated with echoxml -->
   <echoxml>
    <!-- access the corresponding server (set via buildpackage.txt)
         with nested ${@{..}} syntax ! -->
    <copy todir="//${@{client}}/share">
     <fileset dir="@{client}/somedir"/>
    </copy>
   </echoxml>

   <echo>${@{client}}${line.separator}@{client}${line.separator}@{application}${line.separator}@{branding}</echo>

   <!-- another nested xmltask for loop over solutions -->
   <xmltask source="structure.xml">
    <call path="//client[name/text()='@{client}']/*/solution">
     <param path="text()" name="solution"/>
      <actions>
       <echo>@{solution}${line.separator}</echo>
      </actions>
     </call>
   </xmltask>

   </actions>
  </call>
 </xmltask>
</project>
```

If possible you should create buildpackage.txt as valid propertyfile
with the format => Client[x]=Server[x] right away.
Then all you need is the xmltask. Put all your steps to be done into the nested action section as demonstrated with echoxml/copy.
Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<copy todir="//server1/share">
  <fileset dir="client1/somedir" />
</copy>
     [echo] server1
     [echo] client1
     [echo] application_03
     [echo] brand_01
     [echo] solution01
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<copy todir="//server4/share">
  <fileset dir="client4/somedir" />
</copy>
     [echo] server4
     [echo] client4
     [echo] application_03
     [echo] brand_09
     [echo] solution01
     [echo] solution07
     [echo] solution08
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

**-- EDIT after question about conditional action, only if ${@{client}} is set --**

if propertyfile buildpackage.txt contains wrong properties, means server=client instead of client=server, f.e. :

```
Sol-e-45-D=PRODUCTION1
CONNECTION=PRODUCTION3
PRODUCTION4=DFHH
PRODUCTION5=MEGA-5
```

you need some if isset logic. The best is to use the [new if/unless feature](https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) (introduced with ant191) if you're on ant >= 1.9.3, f.e. :

```
<!-- you need to activate that feature via namespaces -->
<project
  xmlns:if="ant:if"
  xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>

 <!-- Import XMLTask -->
 <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>

 <!-- load propertyfile with client=server mappings -->
 <property file="buildpackage.txt"/>

 <!-- loop over all clients -->
 <xmltask source="structure.xml">
  <call path="//client">
   <param path="name/text()" name="client"/>
   <param path="branding/text()" name="branding"/>
   <param path="applications/application/text()" name="application"/>

   <!-- inside action adress params with @{..} syntax ! -->
   <actions>
    <!-- the copy (or whatever) action
         here demonstrated with echoxml -->
   <echoxml if:set="@{client}">
    <!-- access the corresponding server (set via buildpackage.txt)
         with nested ${@{..}} syntax ! -->
    <copy todir="//${@{client}}/share">
     <fileset dir="@{client}/somedir"/>
    </copy>
   </echoxml>

   <echo if:set="@{client}">${@{client}}${line.separator}@{client}${line.separator}@{application}${line.separator}@{branding}</echo>

   <!-- another nested xmltask for loop over solutions -->
   <xmltask source="structure.xml">
    <call path="//client[name/text()='@{client}']/*/solution">
     <param path="text()" name="solution"/>
      <actions>
       <echo if:set="@{client}">@{solution}${line.separator}</echo>
      </actions>
     </call>
   </xmltask>

   </actions>
  </call>
 </xmltask>
</project>
```

Note => the xmltask call has also an if attribute, but the clientname is not known when starting the loop, can't use `<call path="//client" if="@{client}">`

output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<copy todir="//PRODUCTION1/share">
  <fileset dir="Sol-e-45-D/somedir" />
</copy>
     [echo] PRODUCTION1
     [echo] Sol-e-45-D
     [echo] Sol-e-45-D
     [echo] Branding-BLUE
     [echo] Sol-e-45-D
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<copy todir="//PRODUCTION3/share">
  <fileset dir="CONNECTION/somedir" />
</copy>
     [echo] PRODUCTION3
     [echo] CONNECTION
     [echo] Sol-e-45-D
     [echo] Branding-BLUE
     [echo] Sol-e-45-D
```

Otherwise when bound to ant <= 1.9.3 you may use antcontrib if task, as you're already have that taskdef in your snippet :

```
<if>
 <isset property="@{client}"/>
  <then>
   <!-- ... -->
  </then>
</if>
```

Beware, **your antcontrib taskdef definition is wrong** !!, the antcontrib.properties contains only taskdefs for ant < 1.6, declare it like that (assuming antcontrib.jar already on path) :

```
  <project xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">

    <ac:if>
    ...
```

or without namespaces :

```
  <project>

  <!-- Import AntContrib -->
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
  ...
```

Comment: EDIT. now all works perfectly, but there is one problem. If i want to build application1=server1 and application1=server2 and appcation1=server3 - it builds only 1 applicaiton. If i put applicaiton1=server1, application2=server1, applicaiton1=server2 - stull builds applicaiton 1only once.

Comment: @ES Su you have 3 properties named application1. That's not possible. In ant a property once set is immutable. When propertyfile is loaded the first definition, f.e. application1=server1 wins, means the property will have the value server1.

Comment: What if `buildpackage.txt` would be in a format: `client1=server1=server2=server3` `client2=server1` `client3=server1=server2=server3=server4=server5` from one to 5 servers. Is it possible?

Comment: No, a java property has to be key=value, but something like key=value1,value2,value3... is possible. Then use a loop to process your property values.

Comment: Fixed. The solution is: `<property name="token" value="@"/>
        <scp trust="true" verbose="true" localFile="${dest.dir}/@{client}/@{client}.zip" remoteTodir="${scp_username}:${scp_password}${token}@@{val}:${scp_remote_directory}"/> 
        <echo>${line.separator}${line.separator}${line.separator}</echo>
       </sequential>`

Comment: P.S. : to refine my latest comment .. in fact you may use a property like foo=bla=blaa=blaaa, means the value of foo would be bla=blaa=blaaa; It's a valid property but it's unusual..

Comment: PS: fixed already. Works as a charm. Guys are happy ..... but now they need to redesign all. Until that - we will have it as is and no single error :). Thank you very much

Comment: Hi. What id i do have a file where i have (multiple lines) `client=war_name=server1+server2=repository=paramter_x=parameter_y`. Is it possible to split that file (depending on delimiter) and parse as parameter or shall I create another question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @ES Su better create a new question !