# Fetch Codes from SVN using properties file

Tags: ant

I have a scenario, where using `ANT Script` I have to fetch codes from *SVN* using properties file.

The properties files has the property `projectlib` where the libraries used in a module are listed as comma separated values and their corresponding revision numbers are listed in a property `projectlib.revision` below.

I have to fetch projectlib with the respective revision number.

The properties file looks as below:

```
projectliblist=XXXXLib1,XXXXLib2
projectlibrevision=3195,3289
```

For Example, here I have to fetch `XXXXLib1` from `3195` and `XXXXLib2` from `3289`.

I need the logic to match projectlib with respective revision number, not the complete script for this scenario.

I tried with For list, but I don't know how to index the param list.

Comment: Since this is Ant, I assume this is Java and you're trying to associate Jar files? Is this correct? If it is, you should look into using [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org). Ivy works with Ant, so if you already have a `build.xml`, incorporating Ivy into your current build isn't too difficult. This usually works better than writing your own library management schemes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will have with the pair of list properties you show is that (at least using ant-contrib:for) you don't have a way to cross-refer them.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29369019/127035) shows how you can readily cross refer properties using ant-contrib:for / macrodef and might be useful as an example.

For your case, I'd suggest you change the properties structure to be more consumable in Ant, for example:

```
projectliblist=XXXXLib1,XXXXLib2
projectlib.XXXXLib1.revision=3195
projectlib.XXXXLib2.revision=3289
```

which you could consume following the pattern in the answer I linked to above, or possibly:

```
projectliblist=XXXXLib1/3195,XXXXLib2/3289
```

which you could consume in a loop which splits each list element into two parts and passes to a macrodef with two attributes.

Comment: Thank u for your Time . I will try by changing the property structure